# JAVA - Android error: The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again

Tags: android

I made an app which is just working fine. But when i click on "cancel" or "ok" button when i run the program, instead of linking me to result.java, the simulator give me "The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again" Here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class lib_main extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void onAddClick (View botton){

AutoCompleteTextView title = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
AutoCompleteTextView author = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Author); 
AutoCompleteTextView isbn = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.ISBN);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,Result.class);

intent.putExtra("Title", title.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("Author", author.getText().toString()); 
intent.putExtra("ISBN", isbn.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
}

public void onCancelClick(View botton){



Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this,Result.class));

intent.putExtra("Cancel","Cancel");
startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

this is Result.java

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.result);

TextView resultText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultText);

Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle.getString("Cancel")!= null)
{resultText.setText("operation cancel");}
else
{  String book =bundle.getString ("Title");
   String title =bundle.getString ("Author");
   String isbn =bundle.getString ("ISBN");
   resultText.setText(
     getString (R.string.resultOk)+""+book+""+ title+""+isbn);


 }
 }
 }
```

the error log write "No command output when running:'am start-n com.Library.doc/com.Library.doc.lib_main-a android.intent.action.MAIN-c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' in device emulator-5554"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.Library.doc"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".lib_main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity android:name=".Result"
              android:label="@string/result">

    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What would help us debug the problem is the LogCat where the error occured.  That is probably the fastest route to discovering the issue.

Comment: Please post your Manifest file, it's possibly the source of the problem.

Comment: I think your `result.java` actually named as `Result.java`, doesn't it?

Comment: @st0le, okaay.I post it already.
@arhimed, yeah but i did put .Result inside my Manifes file.

Answer (score 1):

Quick question, have you registered both Activities?  If you only provide for one in your manifest file you're going to get this error every time you attempt to do something involving the unregistered activity.

Comment: This is my guess as well, but to really help us out, give the stack log and where some of the line numbers occur.

Comment: yes i did register for both activities but still not working. Is there any other possible error that i do?